# Why the local source code of Volley is different from the one on GitHub?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have imported Volley library with gradle in my android project:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

After Loaded, the local source code is different from the one on GitHub.

For example, the part of code in DiskBasedCache class that starts with line 125.

Local code:

```
        } finally {
        if (cis != null) {
            try {
                cis.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

code on GitHub:

```
}  catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {
        VolleyLog.d("%s: %s", file.getAbsolutePath(), e.toString());
        remove(key);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (cis != null) {
            try {
                cis.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Do anyone know why it is?